# Does PostgreSQL store small arrays inline?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm looking for some documentation that indicates if arrays are stored inline in a record if the record is within the rowsize limit.

However, I notice the rowsize limit is 1.6 TB. It's 8060 b in SQL Server, so it seems things work a little differently.

I need to understand where things are stored in PG. Documentation that explains when values are kept inline and when they're moved to secondary storage would be really helpful.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html